# How to don't write schema name in oracle sql query?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle-xe

I have Workspace/Schema `EDUCATION` in Oracle XE.

In my Java code I want execute queries like this: `SELECT * FROM Table` instead of `SELECT * FROM EDUCATION.Table`.

When I write query without `EDUCATION` I have error: table or view does not exist.

I tried to set the default schema to % (screenshot), but it did not help.
[image]

How to avoid writing Workspace/Schema name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to access tables in other schemas without using the schema name.

One simple way to do this uses [synonyms](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm). In the schema you are connect to:

```
create synonym table for education.table;
```

Then you can use `table` where you would use `education.table`.